# Out params vs. NRVO in the presence of error codes

Tags: c++, optimization, error-handling, nrvo

We have a code base that uses out params extensively because every function can fail with some error enum.
This is getting very messy and the code is sometimes unreadable.

I want to eliminate this pattern and bring a more modern approach.

The goal is to transform:

```
error_t fn(param_t *out) {  
    //filling 'out'
}
param_t param;
error_t err = fn(&param);
```

into something like:

```
std::expected<error_t, param_t> fn() {
    param_t ret;
    //filling 'ret'
    return ret;
}
auto& [err, param] = fn();
```

The following questions are in order to convince myself and others this change is for the best:

1. I know that on the standard level, NRVO is not mandatory (unlike RVO in c++17) but practically is there any chance it won't happen in any of the major compilers?
2. Are there any advantages of using out parameters instead of NRVO?
3. Assuming NRVO happens, is there a a significant change in the generated assembly (assuming an optimized `expected` implementation [perhaps with the boolean representing whether an error occured completly disappear])?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you are inquiring about non-inlined scenatios only? Because once inlining kicks in it's going to be basically 100% equivalent.

Comment: @Frank It concerns whether to structure the code on the assumption of inlining. So it is realy 'when can't inlining take place and can I rely on this (say one day I switch compiler, will my code be slower?)'

Comment: std::expected<> represents a substantial api change (for the better), which makes the refactor sort of non-equivalent. Switching to std::tuple would be a more straightforward 1-to-1 match. In specific, comparing the performance against invoking code that ignores the error would be unfair.

Comment: @Frank I didn't list all the advantages of using ´expected´ as it is not really relevent to the question. In fact, one of the considerations is to DISALLOW ignoring the error (via a nodiscard warning).

Comment: It's relevant in the sense that you care about comparing the two approaches, down to comparing the resulting assembly. However, the comparison is only fair against code that consumes the error, as well as passing only default-initialized `param_t`. So I just want to establish that these assumptions are valid before building an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, a few assumptions:

1. We are looking at functions that are not being inlined. It's going to be almost guaranteed to be absolutely equivalent in that case.
2. We are going to assume that the call sites of the function actually check the error condition before using the returned value.
3. We are going to assume that the returned value has not been pre-initialized with partial data.
4. We are going to assume that we only care about optimized code here.

That being established:

> I know that on the standard level, NRVO is not mandatory (unlike RVO in c++17) but practically is there any chance it won't happen in any of the major compilers?

Assuming that NRVO is being performed is a safe bet at this point. I'm sure someone could come up with a contrived situation where it wouldn't happen, but I generally feel confident that in almost all use-cases, NRVO is being performed on current modern compilers.

That being said, I would never rely on this behavior for program **correctness**. I.E. I wouldn't make a weird copy-constructor with side-effects with the assumption that it doesn't get invoked due to NRVO.

> Are there any advantages of using out parameters instead of NRVO?

In general no, but like all things in C++, there are edge-case scenarios where it could come up. Explicit memory layouts for maximizing cache coherency would be a good use-case for "returning by pointer".

> Assuming NRVO happens, is there a a significant change in the generated assembly (assuming an optimized expected implementation [perhaps with the boolean representing whether an error occured completly disappear])?

That question doesn't make that much sense to me. `expected<>` behaves a lot more like a `variant<>` than a `tuple<>`, so the "boolean representing whether an error occured completly disappear" doesn't really make sense.

That being said, I think we can use std::variant to estimate:

https://godbolt.org/g/XpqLLG

It's "different" but not necessarily better or worse in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have a few questions: First, why is your assumption 3 nescessary? If we use the same partial initialization in both cases I don't see any difference. Second, for the `variant` comment, I'm thinkinh  we usually only test whether there was an error immediately after calling the function, so the "tag" of the `variant` can  be optimized away.

Comment: @OmerRosler Assumption #3 is necessary because otherwise, you could reuse a partially baked result multiple times, only paying the cost once. As far as the variant is concerned, this is mostly covered by Assumption #1. Since the code generating the function does not know how the result will be used, it has no choice but to generate the tag and store it in the result. However, (in the case of `expected<>`), unless your error type manages to be smaller than a `bool` (good luck with that), then you will come out ahead because of the overlapping storage between the error and the payload.

Comment: I see what you mean with #3, and indeed this is the use case. As for the tag, it is not the same as a full blown variant if you can never switch between an err5or and return (the tag is `const`) so I'm thinking the compiler can elide this variable altogether (because it sees how it used completly)